# How to set selected option in select box magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, uicomponent

I have a select box in filter section of admin grid. I need to set default selected option. Here is my code

**Model/Config/Source/Errortype.php**

```
<?php
namespace Bridge\ErrorNotification\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Errortype implements ArrayInterface
{
  public function toOptionArray()
  {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($this->getOptions() as $value => $label) {
        $result[] = [
             'value' => $value,
             'label' => $label,
         ];
    }

    return $result;
  }

  public function getOptions()
  {
    return [
        'select' => __('Select'),
        '404' => __('404'),
        'System Error' => __('System Error'),
        'Login Failed' => __('Login Failed'),
    ];
  }
 }
```

**view/adminhtml/ui_componenet/listing.xml**

```
    <column name="error_type" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Error Type</label>
            <options class="Bridge\ErrorNotification\Model\Config\Source\Errortype"/>
            <filter>select</filter>
            <dataType>select</dataType>
        </settings>

    </column>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code, i hope it will work.

> view/adminhtml/ui_componenet/listing.xml

```
<column name="error_type" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Error Type</label>
        <options class="Bridge\ErrorNotification\Model\Config\Source\Errortype"/>
        <caption translate="true">Your default option</caption>
        <filter>select</filter>
        <dataType>select</dataType>
    </settings>
</column>
```

Comment: caption is not showing in select box